# Django Model Field - is there anyway to define a field that stores an object

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm trying to add Django to my react project. Currently, I'm stuck on defining correlating model fields in Django to what I had in React state.

This is what my old state looks like (when I stored all the info directly in the state

[image: This is what my old state looks like (when I stored all the info directly in the state)]

This is what my new state looks like (when I fetched the data from api and stored it into the state

[image: This is what my new state looks like (when I fetched the data from api and stored it into the state)]

This is the JSON file I'm using to load the data to django database

[image: This is the JSON file I'm using to load the data to django database]

The reason I want to have "teamBackground", "textColor", "votedUpColor", "votedDownColor" properties is that I want to be able to style each team.

**My question is how can I convert the values of these properties from string to object?**

I tried defining these properties as CharField and JSONField, but they don't seem to be working. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Decoding JSON: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects cannot be stored in a relational database AFAIK. You also dont need to store them. There are a few possible solutions to your problem.

1. You can create separate relations for  teamBackground, textColor, votedDownColor, votedUpColor. All of these relations would have one column, 'color'. This may be the better solution if you plan to add more attributes to any of these classes. You would then have a one to one relationship between these relations and your original relation.
2. You can add them as columns in your current relation. While this is probably the most simple way to do it, its not scalable. If you need a different object for teamBackground, textColor, votedDownColor, votedUpColor, then you probably need a separate relation for them as well. However if you are looking for a hack, then you can just add their colors to your original relation instead of adding the object.
3. Again, kind of a hack but you can convert the objects to a JSON string, and then save that string as a column in your relation. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for more information about decoding and encoding JSON in python.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Just to clarify your first solution. To solve my problem, I would create individual tables for teamBackground, textColor, votedDownColor, votedUpColor; then use foreign key to refer them to the table that I have right now?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant

Comment: If I solved your question, please select my answer as the correct answer :)